# how to you trace where your android code executed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm learning to develop android game/application. But sometimes, I don't know if it reach a certain code for debug. How to you place a debug code to see if that line of code has been executed?

if you know javascript, sometimes, I place the alert("you reach here"). so I know that line of code has been executed.

How do you go about doing that in java for android app in eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Logs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html). Logs can be viewed using [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html).

For more on debugging in android go through there docs :

Official docs: 
[Debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html) in android.

Unofficial docs:
[Debugging](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLogging/article.html) in android.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I like using a toast so I can see if I don't have the device attached to an IDE.

Something like:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```